# Oracle Query [need subquery?]

Tags: oracle

assuming I have the following table:

```
NUM  TYPE  STAT   ERR
123   10      6    62
123   10      6    62
123   10      6    62
123   17      4     0
321   10      6    62
321   10      6    62
```

I'm currently using the following query:

```
select MIN(NUM) as NUMBER
     , MIN(STAT) as STATUS
     , MIN(ERR) as ERROR
     , MIN(retry) as RETRY 
 from TABLE_TB 
where ERR=62 
group by NUM 
having count(ERR) > 1;
```

The output will be:

```
NUM  TYPE  STAT   ERR  RETRY
123   10      6    62      3
321   10      6    62      2
```

That's ok, but what I need is that the query will output only `NUM` WITH ERR=62 but also with ERR = 0 excluding those who have ERR=62 but without ERR=0. Taking the first table as example, the query should output

```
NUM  TYPE  STAT   ERR  RETRY
123   10      6    62      3
```

This because NUM 123 has ERR=62 (3 occurrency) but also ERR=0. So, NUM 321 will be excluded because even if has ERR=62, it doesn't have ERR=0.

Hope is cliear :)

Thank you very much.
Lucas

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT num
     , MIN(type) AS type
     , MIN(stat) AS status
     , MIN(err) AS err
     , COUNT(*) AS retry
FROM table_tb
WHERE err != 0 AND
      num IN (SELECT num FROM tb WHERE err = 0)
GROUP BY num;
```

or do without a subquery:

```
SELECT num
     , MIN(CASE WHEN err != 0 THEN type END) AS type
     , MIN(CASE WHEN err != 0 THEN stat END) AS stat
     , MIN(CASE WHEN err != 0 THEN err END) AS err
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN err != 0 THEN 1 END) AS retry
FROM table_tb
GROUP BY num
HAVING COUNT(DECODE(err, 0, 1)) > 0;
```

**Output:**

```
+-----+------+------+-----+-------+
| NUM | TYPE | STAT | ERR | RETRY |
+-----+------+------+-----+-------+
| 123 |   10 |    6 |  62 |     3 |
+-----+------+------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you to show me the subquery example (and w/out). I still have to try it, but the concept is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first filter the table on `err in (62, 0)` and then find how many distinct error types you have (you want 2, since you have two error codes that you're interested in).

Once you have that information, you can then filter on rows where the err = 62 and the distinct count = 2 - e.g.:

```
WITH results as (select num,
                        type,
                        stat,
                        err,
                        retry,
                        count(distinct err) over (partition by num) num_err_types
                 from   table_tb
                 where  err in (62, 0))
select min(num) as nmbr,
       min(stat) as status,
       min(err) as ERROR,
       min(retry) as retry
from   results
where  err = 62
and    num_err_types = 2;
```

I used the `COUNT()` analytic function to find the distinct count - this way, the value is added to each row, regardless of the error code, which is what allows us to filter on it in the final query.

Comment: Thank you, this seems a little bit complicated for me, but I'll try it soon hoping that I can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps you can try this way, simple and sweet...

`select MIN(NUM) as NUMBER
     , MIN(STAT) as STATUS
     , MAX(ERR) as ERROR
     , Count(*) as RETRY 
 from TestTable 
where ERR IN (62 ,0)
group by NUM 
having count(ERR) > 1 AND MIN(ERR)=0;`

Comment: Thank you, yes it's very simple and it seems it works perfect!